# Timer Switch Wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

When trying to wire this timer switch for a bath fan I had the breaker flip when all of my neutrals were spliced together. The neutral in the furthest left of the picture was carrying current when the breaker was on. The bottom black wire pointing towards the camera (furthest to the left that is not connected) is the load wire. Please help me connect all of the wires.
Thanks,
Cody[image]

Comment: first, you don't join all neutrals, neutrals from separate circuits must be kept separate.  Second, not all white wires are neutral.  Lots of white wires are hots in "switch loops".  Joining them to other whites would be disastrous.  You can tell by how they were wired before.  How was this wired before?

Comment: Being inexperienced I did not snap a picture before, so I do not remember how it was wired before. As far as I can tell there was wiring for a light top left, panel wiring top left as well, light (currrently hooked up), and vanity light 3rd from the left. Not sure what the furthest right wiring is for. How would I troubleshoot to find out?

Comment: wait, how many switches are in this box?  Is the single wire-nut something you found that way and did not disturb?

Comment: Yes, how many switches were originally present here?

Comment: This looks like a two-gang box, but there may have been a double switch in one location.